# Is it safe to disable the bare/naked/root domain example.com and use www.example.com only?

Tags: no-www, www

This is *[Making a DNS setup for 20+ domains hosted on the same IP-address more manageable](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/112306/making-a-dns-setup-for-20-domains-hosted-on-the-same-ip-address-more-manageable)* continued.

We're already using the www version as primary. Each `www` is a `CNAME` to `@`, and it's `@` resolves to an IP address.

For convenience, I consider resolving each `www` to a common, shared `CNAME`, and dropping `@` altogether because it [can't be a CNAME](https://superuser.com/questions/264913/cant-set-example-com-as-a-cname-record/264914#264914).

Provided the website doesn't link to *example.com* anywhere internally, is  it a good idea to only keep *www.example.com*. I figured if someone types *example.com* and it does not exist, the browser will auto-try *www.example.com*, right?

Comment: Browser doesn't auto try www, it's DNS system who redirect traffic from naked domain `example.com` to `www.example.com`

Comment: @Goylio DNS can't do redirects on its own.  Its always a web server that does the redirects.

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers may fallback to www. For example in firefox it's controlled by 
`browser.fixup.alternate.enabled=true` and `browser.fixup.alternate.prefix=www.` But rely on this behavior is a bad idea, at least for two reasons:

1. There is no promise that all browsers will fallback to www or it will be enabled in firefox.
2. It will take an extra request and extra time.

Comment: I don't think any browser auto tries for www version. If naked domain is unresolvable; it will be simply error.

Comment: @DavChana This answer is correct, Firefox does auto-try the `www` dpending on settings.  I've personally always found it to be very annoying.